# Is there a defined way to access, and change, printer properties (e.g. Copies, Orientation) via powershell scripting?

Tags: .net, shell, powershell, printing, wmi

Over the last month or so I've begun using powershell to automate many of the tedious office tasks I'm required to do. It's become a useful tool but I've come to a road block either due to a shortcoming in Powershell capabilites or an oversight in my thought process.

Every morning I have to print out various reports, from different printers and for multiple people, before we start our days. I've setup a scheduled task through powershell to print these off and this works perfectly fine, but I seem to be unable to change the printer settings to the matching requirements for the documents I'm printing.

I have code similar to this:

```
$kyo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "ShareName='Kyocera CS 300i KX'"
$kyo.DefaultCopies = 2
Start-Process "C:\Path\To\Reports\That Need Printing.doc" -Verb Print
```

When I read the documentation for the Win32_Printer class, it said that the properties in which DefaultCopies is located were read only, however when I bring this property up in powershell, it has a "set" capability. And there are no errors when I assign a new number to the property. But this assignment doesn't transfer over to the printer when printing. Has powershell lied to me? If so, is there a way to access and change, with powershell, the properties provided by the printers properties dialog?

I know that I could just use a loop to print off the documents in copies, but then that stops our printer from auto-rotating the copies and I have to manually sort them. I also know that this makes me sound lazy, but I have about 20 copies of each document I have to print and If I weren't lazy I wouldn't I wouldn't be trying to automate this.